# How do I add response from TextBox? c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created my own control which contains TextBox control as a child control. this textbox has autopostback set on. when the postback is called I dont get any text in request.querrystring.
where should I specify text entered into texbox will be send to response ? or is there any easier way of sending this information? I want to have the entered text once again in textbox after postback.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dynamically created controls, you need to create them and add them to the control tree in the Page_Init() event; Page_Load() is too late, and Page_PreRender() is way too late.

Once in the control tree, the runtime will restore the state of the control for you after a postback. You can access the contents of the control using `myTextBox.Text` -- you don't need to use `Request.QueryString`

For a control that only contains a TextBox, things would be much easier if you used a user control rather than an INamingContainer. That way, you could just use `<asp:TextBox>` in your .ascx markup.

Answer (score 0):

A custom control?  Any posted control like this loads its data in LoadPostData method.  You can override this in your custom control class, and access the value from teh control via:

var text = postDataCollection[textboxID];

The textbox within your custom control has to have an ID.

If you are talking something else, let me know the specifics.

Thanks.

Comment: hi thanks for response. 
this is shortened code of my control. This control will cause postback but no response is sent back. maybe you are right with loadpostdata but i dont have this method to be overriden in my control.  


    public class my_control : Control, INamingContainer
    {

        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {

            TextBox mytextbox= new TextBox();
            mytextbox.ID = "name";
            mytextbox.AutoPostBack = true;
            Controls.Add(mytextbox);
         }
     }

Comment: My apologies.  Some controls implement this, but since you are inheriting from control, add the namespace IPostbackDataHandler, which will add this for you, and allow you to process postback data.  You should be able to get it via the ID... but it would be the clientID or uniqueID (forget which one).

Answer (score 0):

1. (TextBox)Control.FindControl("control id")
2. get  dynamic control's value in postback   ,  Request.Form("control client id")